# How does SelectFromModel() work from from_model.py?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, supervised-learning

```
fsel = ske.ExtraTreesClassifier().fit(X, y)

model = SelectFromModel(fsel, prefit=True)
```

I am trying to train a data set over the **ExtraTreesClassifier** How does the function  **SelectFromModel()** decide the importance value and what does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the documentation for [`SelectFromModel`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html):

> threshold : string, float, optional default None
>
> The threshold value to use for feature selection. Features whose importance is greater or equal are kept while the others are discarded. If “median” (resp. “mean”), then the threshold value is the median (resp. the mean) of the feature importances. A scaling factor (e.g., “1.25*mean”) may also be used. If None and if the estimator has a parameter penalty set to l1, either explicitly or implicitly (e.g, Lasso), the threshold used is 1e-5. Otherwise, “mean” is used by default.

In your case `threshold` is the default value, `None`, and the mean of the `feature_importances_` in your ExtraTreesClassifier will be used as the threshold.

#### Example

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

iris = load_iris()
X, y  = iris.data, iris.target
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model = SelectFromModel(clf)
SelectFromModel(estimator=ExtraTreesClassifier(bootstrap=False, 
            class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False),
        norm_order=1, prefit=False, threshold=None)
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.threshold_)
#0.25
print(model.estimator_.feature_importances_)
#array([0.09790258, 0.02597852, 0.35586554, 0.52025336])
print(model.estimator_.feature_importances_.mean())
#0.25
```

As you can see the fitted `model` is an instance of `SelectFromModel` with `ExtraTreesClassifier()` as the estimator. The threshold is `0.25`, which is also the mean of the feature importances of the fitted estimator. Based on the feature importances and threshold the model would keep only the 3rd and 4th features of the input data (those with an importance greater than the threshold). You can use the `transform` method of the fitted `SelectFromModel()` class to select these features from the input data.

Comment: But how feature_importances_ is calculated? Is it the accuracy reached using only one feature from the input input vecor (ie. X)?

Comment: @MikeITExpert See the documentation for [`ExtraTreesClassifier.feature_importances_`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.feature_importances_). Short answer to your question is no.

Comment: Note: better to comment `#min_impurity_split=None` otherwise you get `TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_impurity_split'` due to it has been removed from the latest version(1.0) [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69521398/10452700)