# Could anyone recommend how to fix this error?

Tags: python

I am trying to create conda environment but I keep getting this error:

[image]

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_impurity_split'

Comment: not sure how the error is related to 'conda environment' ? the screen snap you have there is something else. if you are using `DecisionTreeRegressor` from sklearn pls recheck its parameter. `min_impurity_split` is not part of it, where is the source for using it?

Comment: I use the parameter

Comment: model = DecisionTreeRegressor(ccp_alpha=0.0, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
                              max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None, 
                              min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                              min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2)

Comment: the code was working well but when I try to create conda environment  I started getting this error. I thought because i install the wrong version of scikit-learn

Comment: I would say check the sklearn version on both in base and your new conda environment. something like this `import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)`

Comment: what version of Sklean do you recommend me to use

Comment: The version on my environment Sklearn==1.0

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give us the code

Comment: the parameter `min_impurity_split` has been removed from the latest version(1.0). If you still want to run it, go for this version `pip install  scikit-learn==0.23.2`

Comment: I installed scikit-learn==0.23.2 and it does work, I really appreciate your support. thank you all

Comment: you are welcome! added as an answer for future readers ; you can accept it :),

Answer (score 2):

The parameter min_impurity_split has been removed from the latest version(1.0). If you still want to run it, go for this version `pip install  scikit-learn==0.23.2`

Code in question

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
model = DecisionTreeRegressor(ccp_alpha=0.0, criterion='mse', max_depth=None, max_features=None,
                              max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0, 
                              min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2)
```

Note: Added for future reference.